# Coldfusion send email

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have function that checks the form and if the form is fine, it will open a modal notifying the user that there request has been sent(via email). However, I am having a hard time to send the email once the form has been submitted.

I have the following modal that will appear when the user submits the button:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h3 style="text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px;">Request Sent</h3>
        <p style="text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; margin-top:28px">For another request, please click <a id="marketingHome" href="marketing.cfm">here</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The following code displays the modal:

```
    if (reqName.value != "" || email.value != "" || phone.value != "" || mngrName.value != "" ||
       dept.value != "" || reqDate.value != "" || detailed_descrp.value != "" || optns.selectedIndex != 0){
         modal.style.display = "block";
    }
```

The following coldfusion code is where I will send an email. The issue I am having is calling the coldfusion code below when the form has been validated and ready to be send. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<CFIF isdefined("form.requestername")>
            <cfset #requestername# = '#form.requestername#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #requestername# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.email")>
            <cfset #email# = '#form.email#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #email# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.phone")>
            <cfset #phone# = '#form.phone#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #phone# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.managername")>
            <cfset #managername# = '#form.managername#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #managername# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.department")>
            <cfset #department# = '#form.department#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #department# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.requested_due_date")>
            <cfset #requested_due_date# = '#form.requested_due_date#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #requested_due_date# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.options")>
            <cfset #selected_options# = '#form.options#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #selected_options# = ''>
        </CFIF>

        <CFIF isdefined("form.detailed_description")>
            <cfset #detailed_description# = '#form.detailed_description#'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset #detailed_description# = ''>
        </CFIF>
        
        <!--- Added "#MailFromName#, which displays User Name and CC to CC the Manager. Also the failto. --->
        <cfmail from="#mailfrom# (#MailFromName#)" to="#SendTo#" cc="#cc#" subject="MARCOM Form" server="server" port="theport#" type="html" failto="touser">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        ##customers {
                            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            width: 100%;
                        }

                        ##customers td, ##customers th {
                            border: 1px solid ##ddd;
                            padding: 8px;
                        }

                        ##customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: ##f2f2f2;}

                        ##customers th {
                            padding-top: 12px;
                            padding-bottom: 12px;
                            text-align: left;
                            background-color: ##6297BC;
                            color: white;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <cfoutput>
                        <table id="customers" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="text-align:center" colspan="2">Marketing and Communications Job Request Form</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:50% !important">Requestor Name:</td>
                                <td>#requestername#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>E-mail Address:</td>
                                <td>#email#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone:</td>
                                <td>#phone#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Manager Name:</td>
                                <td>#managername#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Department:</td>
                                <td>#department#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Requested Due Date:</td>
                                <td>#requested_due_date#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Project type:</td>
                                <td>#selected_options#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align:top">Description of the requested job:</td>
                                <td>#detailed_description#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> 
                    </cfoutput>
                </body>
            </html>
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to submit form data using modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524719/how-to-submit-form-data-using-modal)

Comment: @DanBracuk: What I am trying to attempt is when the user submits the form, it sends the form via email and the modal appears notifying the user (which appears shortly which is not the desire outcome). I would like the form to submit without the modal closing right away when the form is submitted so the user can read context of the modal and close the modal once done.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to not use a modal.  Instead, have a ColdFusion page that processes the form, shows information to the user, and perhaps has links for other things.  I see this approach used on sites where I order food or book tee times.

Comment: @DanBracuk: I do agree however if the user reloads the page where it process the form, it resends. Not sure how to prevent that.

Comment: @DanBracuk: I was able to send an email using xmlhttprequest [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest]. However, I am not sure how I would pass in the values

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you for your help. Went with your suggestion and it works fine. Thank you again

Comment: Not related to the issue, but the cfif/cfelse code could be cleaned  up a lot by replacing it with cfparam's, and removing the excess pound signs..

Comment: @SOS Thank you for the suggestion. Will look up how to use cfparam's. I am fairly new to Coldfusion. Do you happen to know a way to upload the document?

Comment: @RobertoFlores First, you should be able to significantly clean up your variable logic by simply using ternary logic: `requestername = form.requestername ?: ''......`. Those will do the non-nulling logic that you're trying to accomplish. Second, I would strongly caution about the security implications of this email. You shouldn't allow user input without some validation and cleanup. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html